# access forbidden by rule on nginx for specific IP is not working on one of my websites

Tags: nginx, wordpress

Using this nginx configuration code:

```
#
# Nginx virtual host config file - managed by Ansible
#
# mytestpage
#


  # Force HTTP requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mytestpage.com mytestpage.com;
    return 301 https://www.mytestpage.com$request_uri;
}
  # include servers/default.conf;

server {

    #in the future we are going to use http2 we will enable the following line:
    #listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen  443 ssl;

# include servers/default.conf;
   root  /var/opt/httpd/ebdocs;

    server_name www.mytestpage.com mytestpage.com;

       # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/pki/tls/certs/certificate_com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/certificate_com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/eblogs/https/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/eblogs/https/error.log;

    #include whitelist/default.conf;

    include rewrites/default.conf;

    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make nginx serve static files instead of Apache
    # NOTE this will cause issues with bandwidth accounting as files wont be logged
    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wmv|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|htm|html|js|css|svg)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_name $host;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4433;
      }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on <serverIP>:8080
    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_name $host;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4433;

    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
    }

set_real_ip_from 195.234.12.3; # Ip/network of the reverse proxy (or ip received into REMOTE_ADDR)
real_ip_header Incap-Client-IP;

      # restrict access to the admin to internal users
    location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        allow 123.123.42.3;
        deny all;
    }
    location /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php {
        allow all;
    }
      error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
"[error] 576#576: *4578331 access forbidden by rule, client: 123.123.42.3, server: www.mytestpage.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mytestpage.com", referrer: "https://www.mytestpage.com/wp-login.php""
```

when I want to login to my wordpress site.

This is expected for an IP that is not *123.123.42.3* (not an actual IP), but I'm accessing the website using that IP using incapsula as a proxy.

The weird part is that this exact same configuration (with just the server name which is different of course) works fine in other websites I have in my server but not in this website in particular.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.